# Помогите дописать запрос LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
  var query1 = from some in context.Услуга
                         group some by some.Тип into q
                         select new
                         {    Тип=q.Key,
                              id= // тут должно быть минимальное значение id, чей тип равен ключу
                         };
```

Comment: Вы используете `Entity Framework` или что? Опишите подробнее

Comment: Да, Entity Framework. Нужно вывести уникальные значения типа услуги и её id (в БД есть несколько услуг с одинаковым типом, но разными id, какое из их вывести, не принципиально). @Андрей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам должно подойти такое:

```
var услуги = context.Услуга.GroupBy(у => у.Тип).Select(group => group.First());
```

Группируем по типу, затем из каждой группы берем первый элемент

Comment: Не совсем так. Вы выводите один тип, а мне нужно вывести все, которые есть в таблице. @Андрей

Comment: @BlueJeans, добавьте тогда пример данных, содержащихся в таблице и пример того что надо получить

Comment: Например, в таблице есть такие данные: id 1 Тип Йога, id 2 Тип Массаж, id 3 Тип Йога. Нужно получить в результате: id 1 Тип Йога, id 2 Тип Массаж. Второй раз повторяющийся тип не берем. @Андрей

Comment: @BlueJeans, обновил ответ

Comment: @BlueJeans Дубликаты в таблице услуг -- очень плохо. Лучше бы устранили дублирование, а не боролись бы с последствиями.

Comment: @A K Я просто не всю таблицу привела, к услугам с одинаковыми названиями привязаны разные работники.

Comment: @BlueJeans, в таком случае нужно было бы разделить на разные таблицы: 1. Услуги; 2. Работники и между ними связь многие-ко-многим

Comment: @Андрей Наверное, да. У меня идет оформление заказа, клиент выбирает услугу из комбобокса, в следующем выбирает одного из работников, что надает услуги данного типа. Работники хранятся в отдельной таблице, как и услуги и договора.

Comment: @Андрей Переписала запрос и подключила к комбобоксу.
            var query1 = from some in context.Услуга
                         orderby some.Тип
                         select new { 
                             Тип=some.Тип,
                             id = some.idУслуги,
                         };
            b.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();// так работает, но выводит все записи.           
           
           b.ItemsSource = (query1.GroupBy(у => у.Тип).Select(group => group.First())).ToList();// так не работает, окно с комбобоксом не загружается. В чем проблема?

Comment: Зачем вы опять выбираете из query1, выбирайте из `context.Услуга`, как я вам и написал в ответе

Comment: @Андрей Так сразу сделала, тоже не работало.

Comment: Трудно сказать, нужно запускать под отладчиком и по шагам смотреть

Comment: Без .First() работает.  
@Андрей

Comment: @Андрей Нужно было вместо group.First() использовать group.FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Без .First это не совсем то